# ng-repeat in ChartJS AngularJS

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, chart.js

I have the following difficulty.
At the time of displaying the data with ng-repeat it does not show me any results.
you can see my code in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/roalroga/pen/mdyJEyq?editors=1000)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>


<script>
  var app = angular.module("RodoApp", ["chart.js"]);
  app.controller("ChartController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.person = [
      {
        "name": "Rodrigo",
        "number": 5,
      },
      {
        "name": "Carlos",
        "number": 11,
      },
      {
        "name": "Arnold",
        "number": 20,
      }
    ];


    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.data = [];

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.person.length; i++) {
      $scope.labels.push($scope.person[i].name);
      $scope.data.push($scope.person[i].number);
    }

    $scope.options = {
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'title'
      } };

  });
</script>
<body ng-app="RodoApp" ng-controller="ChartController">

  <div ng-repeat="t in person">
    <div>{{t.name}} - {{t.number}}</div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div ng-repeat="options in person">
    <canvas id="{{options.name}}" class="chart chart-pie"  chart-options="options" chart-data="options.data" chart-labels="options.labels" />
  </div>
</body>
```

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

**RESULT**

*I need to count the IdSurveyQuestionAnswer to assign to their respective IdSurveyQuestion*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with the code that you've posted.  The key ones that I see that will get the chart rendering happening are as follows:

**First**, your `ng-repeat` is using `options`, but you also have a scope variable called `options`, and I think they are clashing (or at the very least, not doing what you think they are doing).

Changing `$scope.options = {...}` to `$scope.chartOptions = {...}`, and `chart-options="options"` to `chart-options="chartOptions"` will fix this.

**Second**, your `ng-repeat` is looking for `chart-data` and `chart-labels` inside each `person`.  You've only defined `name` and `number`, so there is no data to display.

On this, I can see that you've iterated over the `person` array and dropped all the information into a scope `data` and `labels` array.

That means that while you are rendering a chart per person, you're effectively rendering the **same** chart each time.

A full working version follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>


<script>
  var app = angular.module("RodoApp", ["chart.js"]);
  app.controller("ChartController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.person = [
      {
        "name": "Rodrigo",
        "number": 5,
      },
      {
        "name": "Carlos",
        "number": 11,
      },
      {
        "name": "Arnold",
        "number": 20,
      }
    ];


    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.data = [];

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.person.length; i++) {
      $scope.labels.push($scope.person[i].name);
      $scope.data.push($scope.person[i].number);
    }

    $scope.chartOptions = {
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'title'
      } 
    };

  });
</script>
<body ng-app="RodoApp" ng-controller="ChartController">

  <div ng-repeat="t in person">
    <div>{{t.name}} - {{t.number}}</div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div ng-repeat="options in person track by $index">
    <canvas ng-attr-id="{{options.name}}" class="chart chart-pie"  chart-options="chartOptions" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" />
  </div>
</body>
```

While this renders the charts, the make up of the data and why you want to repeat this is something that you'll need to think about, and possible ask another question on.